# Finding the central series of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

So my question is just like the title. 
I have to find the central series of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$.

I have found the $$Z(GL_n(\mathbb R))=\{aI_n(\mathbb R)| a \in \mathbb R \}.$$
And I don't know how to do next.

Any helpful answers for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you state your goal more precisely? Wikipedia says: "A group need not have a central series. In fact, a group has a central series if and only if it is a nilpotent group." and the general linear group is not nilpotent.

Comment: You probably meant to say you have to find the upper central series. In this case, you need to show that $PGL_n=GL_n/Z(GL_n)$ has trivial center.